# Uncaught ReferenceError: compile is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, forms, auto-generate

I'm trying to make a canned message generator for my personal use. I cannot get this second button to work. Im way off somewhere. This is my first attempt at coding so please help..

```js
     function write_response(){
      let verify_statement = document.getElementById('verifyStatment')
      let caseData = {   
        id: Date.now(),
        tasks: document.getElementById('task').value,
        slTag: document.getElementById('slTagId').value,
        orderId: document.getElementById('orderId').value,
        welcome: document.getElementById('welcome').value,
        closing: document.getElementById('closing').value,
        signature: document.getElementById('signature').value,
        sbtLevel: document.getElementById('sbtLevel').value,
        rma: document.getElementById('rmaId').value
      }   
    
      
      verify_statement.innerHTML = "Welcome Please Verify " + " Your task is " + (caseData.tasks) + " SL Tag: " + (caseData.slTag) + " Order #: " + (caseData.orderId) 
      + " RMA #: " + (caseData.rma);


    function para(){
      let compiled_all = document.getElementById('compileAll')
      let caseData = {   
        id: Date.now(),
        tasks: document.getElementById('task').value,
        slTag: document.getElementById('slTagId').value,
        orderId: document.getElementById('orderId').value,
        welcome: document.getElementById('welcome').value,
        closing: document.getElementById('closing').value,
        signature: document.getElementById('signature').value,
        sbtLevel: document.getElementById('sbtLevel').value,
        rmaId: document.getElementById('rmaId').value
      }

             
        compiled_all.innerHTML ==(caseData.welcome) + " We regret to inform you that during the provisioning of your recent order(s)# " + (caseData.orderId) + " we encountered a delay in provisioning. This delay is due to " +  (caseData.tasks) + " We will provide more information as it becomes available to us. Please let us know if you have any further questions or concerns and we would be happy to assist you."
        }

      



    };
```

The first button generates the paragraph no prblem but once i try the second button i get the error in the subject.

```html
   <div class="formBox">
        <input type="button" value="Verify" onclick="write_response() ;"/>
   
      </div>
    <div>
    <b>Always Double CHECK!</b>
    <p id="verifyStatment">  </p>
    </div>
    <div class="formBox">
      <input type="button" value="Generate" onclick="para() ;"/>
    </div> 

    <div>
      <b>You Lucky dog you ;)</b>
      <p id="compileAll">  </p>
      </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: My goal is to use the function  para() to make a if statment to generate a different paragraph depending on the value of the caseData Tasks property.

Comment: It looks like your `para()` function is declared inside the `write_response()` one; the "Generate" button has no access to `para()`.

Comment: okay thank you. I will try that! thank you for a response @secan

Comment: @secan thanks kind sir.. Its working now. I shall add the ifs next.. Your help has been much appreciated.